# Array returns false when i know it should be true

Tags: arrays, string, bash

I know that this particular volume should be coming out as true but it keeps returning as false. Can anyone see what is wrong with it? My guess is it has something to do with the if statement but i have no idea what. the "3D/Gather" are 2 seperate strings but i want it so that if they are together then it returns true. This is the start of what is going to be quite a long script so i want to make it a function that i can call upon later on. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
#!/bin/bash
session_path=$PWD/testSess/3DBPvol.proc
outPath=""
sess=$session_path
{
    ThreeD="false"
    while read line; do
            IFS=" "
            arr=$(echo ${line})
            unset IFS
            for i in ${arr[@]} ; do
                    if [[ "$i" =~ "3D" ]] && [[ "$i" =~ "Gather" ]]; then
                            ThreeD="true"
                    fi
            done
    done < "$sess"
    echo "Is 3D? $ThreeD"
}
```

Comment: this looks like shell scripting to me, not php. you may also want to elaborate on what shell you're developing for (sh, bash, zsh, ksh)?

Comment: sorry yeah im using bash

Comment: what does the anatomy of a line look like? also the right side of `=~` does not appear to be a regex?

Comment: What does the contents of `testSess/3DBPvol.proc` look like?

Comment: line = "  line=IL:1302 primaryMin='1348' primaryMax='2248' primaryInc='4'  "

Comment: the proc is a long doco, 3D gather appears as "Input 3D Gather" without quotaions

Comment: @dazza2608 please make the update/edit in your post :)

Comment: Arrays don't "return false", or return true either. They don't return anything. Please fix your title.

Comment: from the if statement that im putting in with the array it does return true or false @EJP

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=$(echo ${line})
```

This doesn't create an array, you'd need extra parens:

```
arr=($(echo ${line}))
```

But you don't actually need the `echo`, this should be enough:

```
arr=(${line})
```

Comment: That actually seems to work alright - at least in my version of bash (4.2.45).

Comment: thats still returning a false to me. am i right in thinking that the / in "3D/Gather" represents a space?

Comment: No, a slash is a slash. And the items in the array can't contain a space, you're splitting on that.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to see if the file under `/proc` contains "3D Gather"? You can do that simply with a `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
session_path=$PWD/testSess/3DBPvol.proc
grep -q '3D Gather' "$session_path" && ThreeD=true || ThreeD=false
echo "Is 3D? $ThreeD"
```

Comment: that doesnt work either unfortunately, its returning blank to me now. I think i do need an array i just need to be able to search for 2 strrings within the array to call up true. Without the 2 words it will call up true for all lines

Comment: I changed my answer to simply use `grep`. If this doesn't work for you then I didn't understand your question. You might want to clarify your question with sample inputs that should match, and others that shouldn't, including relevant corner cases.

Comment: The Grep came up with nothing either, ive modified my original question to help clarify what im trying to do. Thanks for your help

Comment: Add sample lines that should be matched. In your earlier comment it looks like there is a line containing "Input 3D Gather". But if you say the `grep` doesn't match it, then there is no such line. So give a sample of the content of `$PWD/testSess/3DBPvol.proc`. Not the entire content, just the *relevant part*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't need to break the line into a BASH array. Consider this rafactored script that does the same job but with a lot less code:

```
ThreeD="false"
while read line; do
    [[ "$line" == *"3D Gather"* ]] && ThreeD="true" && break
done < "$sess"
echo "Is 3D? $ThreeD"
```